# I read that although pwdLastSet is 0, LastPasswordSet returns null. Is that true?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I'm developing a C# .NET Framework 4.0 library to work with Active Directory.

I need to check if an user has to change his/her password at next logon, and I read that I can know this looking at `pwdLastSet` value.

I am using [UserPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/vstudio/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), and `pwdLastSet` is represented in the `UserPrincipal` class as the LastPasswordSet property.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679430%28VS.85%29.aspx) I read that If `pwdLastSet` value is set to 0 and the User-Account-Control attribute does not contain the UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD flag, then the user must set the password at the next logon.

Can be `LastPasswordSet` zero?

I'm new on this kind of development, and in this [article](http://webactivedirectory.com/active-directory/authenticableprincipal-lastpasswordset-values/) I read that `LastPasswordSet` can't be zero.

I read that although pwdLastSet is 0, LastPasswordSet returns null. Is that true?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can able to set this value as 0. Perform the below steps to set this as 0.

1. Launch LDP.exe and bind to the DS server you want to modify. Make sure you are schema admin, and admin over the partition you are modifying
2. After connecting and binding navigate to the browse menu and select the "Modify" option.
3. Leave the DN blank, type 'schemaUpgradeInProgress' into the Attribute field and in the values field type 1.
4. Click the Add operation and then click the enter button. This will add this command to the entry list.
5. Click the Run button. If you are successful you should see a successful modify message.
6. Go to View -> Tree. Connect to the appropriate base DN.
7. Find the object, right click and select modify
8. In the attribute field, type "pwdLastSet"; in the Values field, type 0; in the operation radio options, select Replace
9. Then click Enter, then click Run to set pwdLastSet as 0.

Regards,

Santhosh.

[www.jijitechnologies.com](http://www.jijitechnologies.com)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I read that although pwdLastSet is 0, LastPasswordSet returns null. Is that true?